# Model Objects Vs. View Objects

Tags: objective-c, ios6

I am currently a college student with almost 2 years of C++ programming experience and have a general question about Objective-c. I am fairly new with Objective-C and the user-interface Xcode offers. I am currently reading the book "iOS Programming: The Big Nerd Ranch Guide". My question is....

What is the difference between a view object and a model object in objective-c?
 - Implementation-wise, and anything else.

Any opinion is great!!!

Comment: This might be of use to you: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/general/conceptual/CocoaEncyclopedia/Model-View-Controller/Model-View-Controller.html